# Android Kotlin Datepicker Dialogue - Missing Features

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker

I am missing few features in my Date picker dialogue using Kotlin

- Missing Cancel & OK buttons
- Today is not highlighted when the dialogue opened (today is 19 and 18 is highlighted)

Can someone please tell me how to fix this

Here is the theme code

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/crimsonAccent</item>-->
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/prim</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Comment: How did you create this DatePicker?

Comment: Just a observation, you said that "Today is not highlighted when the dialogue opened (today is 19 and 18 is highlighted)" but if you observe, the 19 is in a different color because it is highlighted. The 18 is selected when you open the date picker because your upper date limit might be setted to yesterday.

Comment: @Tenfour04, Here is my code  `private val datePickerDialog by lazy {
        DatePickerDialog(requireActivity(), R.style.DialogTheme).apply {
            setTitle(R.string.select_date)`